# Editing header of all HTTP request made by mapbox-gl-native iOS SDK

Tags: ios, mapbox-gl

I'm using mapbox-gl-native SDK. It can be used with custom servers to provide map tilesets. I'm working with a server which needs an API key in the HTTP request header. I want to edit the header for every request and add the API key.
can anyone help me with this?

I'm using [mapbox-gl-native](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) iOS v5.0 (latest untill now)

Comment: Add some code which is used by you in request parameters.

Comment: @SagarChauhan I didn't write any code yet. actually i'm looking for idea of doing it. besides,  i'm not completely familiar with the mapbox-gl-native code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a file named `http_file_source.mm` in `platform/darwin/src/` which is responsible for making HTTP requests. there is a method in this file:

```m
HTTPFileSource::request(const Resource& resource, Callback callback) {
```

in this mehtod you can see this line:

```m
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

this line makes a http request you can add your own header to it, like so: (`value` for header `field`)

```m
[req addValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field]
```